# How do I determine the server path of a file of a class file, from that class's parent class in PHP

Tags: php

I'm trying to find a way to determine the server location of a class from within the class' parent, without hardcoding any values. In other words there is a class called Child.php inside /root/classes/Child/Child.php and it extends Parent.php which is in /root/classes/Parent/Parent.php.

I need a way to have a method inside Parent.php return the path to Child.php

```
class Parent
{
    // Normal constructor stuff

    public function pathToClassFile()
    {
        // return path to class file
    }
}

class Child extends Parent
{
    // Normal constructor stuff
}
```

I then call

```
$dude = new Child();
print $dude->pathToClassFile();
```

Returns

*/root/classes/Child/Child.php*

Comment: I was gonna say debug_backtrace() but it still shows the call to the parent class even if called using $dude->pathToClassFile(). If you are trying to avoid overwriting that method in the child class, you may not be able to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to use Reflection (or at least, the last time I did this). Here's approximately how it works:

parent.php

```
<?php
class ParentClass {
    protected $reflection;
    function filename( ) {
            return $this->reflect( $this )->getFilename( );
    }

    function reflect( $object ) {
            if( !isset( $this->reflection ) ) {
                    $this->reflection = new ReflectionClass( $object );
            }
            return $this->reflection;
    }
}
```

child.php:

```
<?php
require_once( 'parent.php' );
class ChildClass extends ParentClass {
}

$child = new ChildClass( );
echo $child->filename( ) . "\n";
```

Comment: By the way: this is tested. It outputs the filename of the child class, instead of it's parent, which seems to be exactly what you want.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  It's the only one that will work properly across file structures.  @Berry: see the original question from the OP: `I need a way to have a method inside Parent.php return the path to Child.php`

Comment: Hm? I have a method in Parent.php that will return the path to child.php, so I really don't see any issues?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should do it:

```
public function pathToClassFile()
{
    return __FILE__;
}
```

Comment: Think he's looking for the path to the _child_ class, this returns the Parent/Parent.php path.

Comment: Assuming Parent class is in its own file, this would always return the path to the Parent class, not the Child class. To do it for child classes, every class that extends Parent would need a copy of this method implemented.

Comment: You're right, the method has to be overridden in every child class. However, this still satisfies the "without hardcoding any values" requirement, as hacky as it may be.

Comment: This code is meant to be distributed to a larger group of developers, so I can't use 'hacky'. While technically correct, it isn't a production-level solution.